# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined list of lists

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey what I am doing wrong?

```
var list = [{
        name: 'client1'
    },
    {
        name: 'client2'
    },
    {
        name: "client3"
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i]['name'].indexOf(self.autocomplete) !== -1) {
        self.box = self.box + '<li>' + list[i]['name'] + '</li>';
    }
}
```

I getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **for** `loop` is executed for `list.length+1` times.That's why you are obtaining `undefined` for the last `item`.

JavaScript `arrays` are **zero-indexed**: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.

Change

```
for(var i=0; i<=list.length; i++){}
```

To

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){}
```